# How to backup vim configuration with plugins?

Tags: vim

I understand to backup my vimrc file but what about my plugins? Will I have to reinstall them if I move to another machine? Or can I just copy paste the directories in my vim folder ( but what if i go from windows to linux) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, it is sufficient to take the `vimfiles`/`.vim` directory with you.  However, in my experience the Linux builds of Vim are much more fussy about plugin line-endings than the Windows ones.  Therefore, it is worth checking that all of your plugins and other vim configuration files have Unix line endings so that they work on Windows and Linux without issues.

---

In my set-up, I have the whole of `.vim` under version control: this makes synchronising multiple computers very straightforward.  To make this work well, put your `_vimrc` into your `vimfiles` directory and name it (e.g.) `vimrc`.  Then in the place where you normally have `_vimrc` add a file with this content:

```
runtime vimrc
```

Do the same for `_gvimrc` if you have one.  This means you can keep everything in one folder (plugins and `vimrc`) and keep that folder under version control or just synchronise it by some other means if you prefer.

Comment: how do I check the line endings because I've just copied my vimrc file from my windows and now in ubuntu vim won't start because it doesn't recognise the line endings. Actually I can't even open the vimrc file in gedit either...

Comment: I found the solutions here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format#Converting_the_current_file  :)

Answer (score 6):

This might help: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/

Answer (score 4):

In most cases taking the directories with you should do the trick.